# PHPmailer Function Send Mail from PHP

Tags: html, email, send

so i am working on  a contact form in html and i linked it to a sendmail.php file, as i still in the early process i was testing if fields are empty echo something... nothing is appearing. Please check my code it's still in it's early stage i'm afraid i have missed something out:

**HTML**

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" >
<table width="101" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Full Name:</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th width="95" scope="col"><input type="text" name="name" id="to" placeholder="Full Name" /></th><!-- -->
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Telephone:</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"placeholder="Telephone" />
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Subject:</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" /></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Message:</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><textarea name="body" id="body" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></th>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
     <?php

                session_start();

                require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php/';

                $errors = array();



    //if values are null echo null values
    //in my case i kept null on purpose to see if working
    //getting nothing


if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['telephone'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['body']))
                {
                    echo 'Null values';
                }

            ?>
```

Comment: does the file that you are requiring exist there?  Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['telephone'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['body'])){....}
```

should be

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['telephone'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['body'])){.....}
```

On submit input type text are never `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
 require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php/';
```

Try this?

```
require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

You didn't ask to do something as far as I can see.
This might work (all in one file, no need to create a second file)

```
<? 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{ 
if(strlen($_POST['name']) == 0)
{ $error_msg ="- Please, provide us with your name.<br>"; } 
if(strlen($_POST['*****WHATEVER*****']) == 0)
{ $error_msg ="- Fill in your problem :D.<br>"; } 

if(!empty($error_msg))
{ 
echo "<b>Your message can't be send due to the following reason:</b>    <br><br>"; 
echo $error_msg; 
echo "<br>Click on <a href='javascript:history.back(1)'>Go back</a> and provide us with your name.<br><br>"; 
}
else 
{ 
$recipient = "WHO NEEDS TO RECEIVE???";  
$subject = "Subject, can be filled in via input field if you like";  
$header = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body = "Contact script was used on " . date("d-m-Y") . " at " .  date("H:i") . "h.\n"; 
$mail_body .= "Text you like to read:\n"; 
$mail_body .= "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body .= "\n\n -- End of contact --"; 
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); 
print "Your mail is sent and whatever you like to tell them ;)";
}
} 
else 
{ 
?>  
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="contact">
******Then add your tables and label them as you please.****
```